# Any open source projects using to Linq2SQl?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

Is there any open source projects or demo projects using Linq2Sql as primary data layer for accessing and updating all its data?

I am working in a project(asp.net webapp) which has Linq2Sql in DAL. We realized that half way through the project our design is not properly working out. I would like to see how Linq2Sql is being implemented in multilayered project. Any reference or guidance would would be good to.

I am already aware that Entity Framework is preferred way going forward but this project is mostly done in Linq2Sql, so we would like to finish it out.

Answer (score 0):

a year ago, when I tried asp.net MVC I used [nerd dinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) to learn it, if I remember correctly, it's using linq2sql